# Закрываются сетевые папки сами по себе

Tags: windows-10

Закрываются сетевые папки сами по себе.
После открытия сетевой папки через неопределенное время она сама закроется.
Переустановка Windows(10) не помогла.
В чем может быть проблема?
подскажите?

Comment: Ресурс отключается по неактивности (login timeout) - окно закрывается.

Comment: а как это убрать можно ?

Answer (score 1):

На сервере, где расположен удалённый ресурс (сетевая папка) выполните (можно удалённо - скажем, используя psexec) от имени администратора команду:

```
net config server /autodisconnect:60
```

Параметр задаёт время до автоматического отключения по неактивности в минутах.

Допустимые значения - от -1 до 65535.

Значение -1 - вообще выключает отключение по неактивности.

Не указывайте ноль!!! При таком значении соединение отключается сразу по окончании аутентификации.

ЕМНИП изменения вступают в действие после перезапуска службы lanmanserver (либо перезагрузки).